# Coordinating descriptor sets and layouts in Vulkan

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I've been doing research into Vulkan and raytracing through NVidia's [vk_raytrace example](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_raytrace/tree/master/shaders) and I've run into confusion about how coordination between pipeline layouts, GLSL shader "layouts", and descriptor sets happen.

****Primary question:****

I really want to create a single ["layout" file](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_raytrace/blob/master/shaders/layouts.glsl) which can be shared across all shader files regardless of pipeline. Is this possible if the pipeline layouts match only the used descriptor sets within the shader? Would the unused layouts be optimized out when compiling the shader to SPIR-V?

**Other questions:**

- You don't specify the actual "descriptor set" number when creating a pipeline layout, simply some ordering. In the NVidia example they create a "shared" descriptor set between two pipelines, in the main pipeline this is set 1 and in the other its set 0. What is going on here - can set numbers be totally arbitrary?
- I've been looking for examples for multiple push-constants for pipelines - how does this work - and are there any official examples using GLSL?

**Relevant code sections pertaining to the primary question:**

Creation of the Post pipeline where it uses its own descriptor set

```
void RenderOutput::createPostPipeline(const VkRenderPass& renderPass)
{


 // This descriptor is passed to the RTX pipeline
  // Ray tracing will write to the binding 1, but the fragment shader will be using binding 0, so it can use a sampler too.
  bind.addBinding({OutputBindings::eSampler, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, 1, VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT});
  bind.addBinding({OutputBindings::eStore, VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE, 1,
                   VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_RAYGEN_BIT_KHR});
  m_postDescSetLayout = bind.createLayout(m_device);
  m_postDescPool      = bind.createPool(m_device);
  m_postDescSet       = nvvk::allocateDescriptorSet(m_device, m_postDescPool, m_postDescSetLayout);
  //...
  pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts = 
    &m_postDescSetLayout;
  //...
  vkCreatePipelineLayout(m_device, &pipelineLayoutCreateInfo, nullptr, &m_postPipelineLayout);
```

Creation of the Raygen pipeline which uses the shared descriptor set m_offscreen.getDescSet:

```
void SampleExample::createRender(RndMethod method)
{
  //...

  m_pRender[m_rndMethod]->create(
      m_size, {m_accelStruct.getDescLayout(),
               m_offscreen.getDescLayout(),  // This is the shared desclayout
               m_scene.getDescLayout(), 
               m_descSetLayout}, &m_scene);
}
```

Here are the corresponding shader layouts - for the Post pipeline the only relevant file is "post.frag"

```
//...
layout(location = 0) in vec2 uvCoords;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D inImage;

layout(push_constant) uniform _Tonemapper
{
  Tonemapper tm;
};
//...
```

The rest of the layouts get included by *most?* of the raygen shaders layouts - "layouts.glsl":

```
// clang-format off
layout(set = 0, binding = 0)                    uniform accelerationStructureEXT topLevelAS;

// Shared layout
layout(set = 1,   binding = 1)                  uniform image2D         resultImage;
//...
```

Comment: "*In the NVidia example*" There's a *lot* of code in that example. Could you be more specific on where, or better yet, add the code of interest to the question?

Comment: "*Would the unused layouts be optimized out when compiling the shader to SPIR-V?*" SPIR-V compilation does not get access to pipeline layouts.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but if I have unused layouts do they get optimized out during SPIRV compilation? and how would that affect how Vulkan drivers interpret the SPIRV layouts and reconcile them with the pipeline layouts? Where do set numbers play a role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure we're on the same page, let's start with some terminology.

When I say "pipeline layout", what I mean is a `VkPipelineLayout` object and the various components used to build it (descriptor set layouts, etc). There are also descriptor definitions in a shader, which are... the definitions of descriptor resources potentially used by that shader. These are *not* "pipeline layouts" (ignore the fact that the keyword `layout` is used to declare the descriptor and set indices; that's just convenient syntax). Lastly, there are the actual `VkDescriptorSet` objects you create and bind at runtime.

> You don't specify the actual "descriptor set" number when creating a pipeline layout

Yes you do. Set X refers to the X'th index of the array `VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo::pSetLayouts`. Set 0 is the descriptor set `pSetLayouts[0]`.

If the NVIDIA example uses the same descriptor set layout with different set indices in different pipeline layouts, then binding a pipeline that uses the descriptor set layout in a different set index will [disturb the bound descriptor sets](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap14.html#descriptorsets-compatibility). So it must also rebind the descriptor set to the appropriate set index.

That is, the code in question is not trying to maintain binding compatibility between the pipeline layouts; it just wants to be able to use the same descriptor set.

It is fine for a shader module to not define all of the descriptors specified in a pipeline layout. Indeed, it is fine if some descriptors in the pipeline layout is defined by *none* of the shader modules when building a pipeline. The descriptor set layout is what matters; so long as a shader module does not *contradict* the pipeline layout, a `VkDescriptorSet` built against a particular layout will work with a `VkPipeline` object using a `VkPipelineLayout` that includes that descriptor set layout.

Comment: > Yes you do. Set X refers to the X'th index of the array VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo::pSetLayouts. Set 0 is the descriptor set pSetLayouts[0].

But you are stuck with array ordering here. If I want to use a "shared" layout file then I would have to create "dummy" desc sets just to fill up unused indexes - like if I wanted the sets to be numbered 1, 3, 4 this wouldn't be possible - correct? If I interpret your answer correctly you are saying a shared layout file is not possible?

Comment: @RWilco8: "*"shared" layout file*" In your original post, when you mentioned that, you linked to some GLSL code. GLSL does not define the *pipeline layout* (that's why I started my answer with definitions). GLSL must *agree* with the pipeline layout, but the layout is defined by `VkPipelineLayout` and its component parts. So you seem confused by terminology. GLSL is perfectly capable of using whatever set indices it wants. If it doesn't declare something that uses set 2 but does declare something that uses set 3, that's fine.

Comment: I marked your answer correct since it does clear some things up for me, but I am still very confused : ( Hopefully I can get to the bottom of things with some experiments....

Comment: @RWilco8: Vulkan is not a safe API, so experimentation is not an effective way to learn. Something might be broken but happen to work in your circumstance. It's better to read about how Vulkan works and try to internalize it.

Comment: You mention "It is fine for a shader module to not define all of the descriptors specified in a pipeline layout.", but are the performance implications for adding unused descriptors?

Comment: @RWilco8: "Performance implications" relative to what? Relative to having to bind a different descriptor set between otherwise compatible pipelines? Or having to manage different mostly-identical descriptor sets whenever something changes? Because those are the *costs* of making every pipeline completely bespoke and sharing no descriptor sets between them.